# Relational DB functionality for reconciling data ingestion against active database?

Tags: database, oracle, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

I'm trying to write an application which ingests all records in a table from an Oracle database into google cloud storage. The Oracle DB is an active database which has new records added constantly. My concern is when reconciling that all data has made it into the cloud storage that the record counts will change, e.g. my count of records in cloud storage is 1000 and my count in Oracle has increased during ingestion to 1005. Is there functionality in Oracle or other RDBMS for handling this so I can achieve parity during my QA and reconciliation checks?

I have considered using a surrogate key to identify records which have been ingested however the data is extremely large (100s of TB) that I don't know it's feasible to check for all possible keys.

Comment: Questions about recommendations for tools are off-topic here. Please delete and repost to [softwarerecs.se] . Good luck.

Comment: Edited to clarify scope of question, I'm not interested in tools but rather existing RDBMS functionality and best practices

Comment: Post a [mcve] please and read the [help] section about on-topic questions. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, You can use [Oracle Flashback Query (SELECT AS OF)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-0BD1F4BD-894B-47BA-A44B-74BCA4CFD60E) to query what the table looked like the moment before the ingestion began. For example:

```
select count(*) from table1 as of timestamp timestamp '2023-07-19 21:05:00';
```

(Yes, the above syntax looks like a bug, but "timestamp timestamp" really does work here.)

However, your process cannot ALTER the table, or you'll get an error like "ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed". And your process cannot wait too long or you will get an error like "ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 8 with name "_SYSSMU8_3558373158$" too small". In that case, you may need to talk to a DBA about configuring the system to support longer-running statements with more UNDO space.